# How to propagate branch deletes in git?

Tags: git, branch

We have a pretested commit structure for our git repositories along the lines of [this](http://www.joergm.com/2011/05/pre-tested-commits-using-git/), a sort of automated [integration manager](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Integration-Manager-Workflow).

However we have a problem with deleting branches, in that they can be deleted from the devs local repo, and that change can be pushed by the dev to their personal repository, but that change doesn't make it to the 'green' or 'blessed' repo as the build server doesn't trigger a build when the branch is deleted.

If I write a script which gets all of the branches from the devs personal repo and all of the branches from the 'green' repo (bearing in mind that this will have branches from many other devs) and issues a

`git push origin :BranchName`

for each branch that exists in 'green' that is not in personal, will this remove the branches that the dev has deleted in his personal repo, but leave all of the others?

Will this work?  Are there any better solutions than this?

Comment: hmmm.. after re reading the [git-push man page] it seems that this command won't work and will just delete a lot of branches in the remote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your system will be able to catch the removal of the reference to trigger the build, but since the CI instance is pulling from your dev remote personal repo you should use `git remote prune origin` to remove branches on the CI side that were deleted from personal remote repo (assuming origin is the remote name for dev remote repo because it was cloned from there)

As your CI is pushing to the green repo it has an ability to compare the subset of branches on remote side with what it has currently and find the deleted branches. So on CI side you can do something like that on every push:

```
git branch -a | grep {green_repo_remote_name}
```

compare it with list of local branches:

```
git branch
```

and execute

`git push {green_repo_remote_name} :branch_name_that_exists_only_in_green_repo`

**UPDATE:**

As per comment below it seems that the approach above will remove other devs branches from the green repo. My bad.
There are two approaches to resolve that as i see it:

I. stop creating dev branches in green repo, use CI to actually integrate changes:

upon the change from dev personal repo the CI should check this change out, pull an commonly known integration branch from green repo, merge dev branch into it and compile. If success then push back the changes to the green repo

II. Register CI repos as remotes in green repo, play with post-receive hook on green repo side to trigger `git remote prune *`. That will effectively remove all branches the were removed from CI repo for each remote.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Eugene. There are many devs each with their own branches in their own personal repo, so green may contain many branches which exist in green which are not in the current local repo (which is a clone from one devs personal repo).  will this approach not delete all branches from green which are not in the current devs personal repo, ie potentially delete all branches which belong to other devs?

Comment: See update, please. I was a bit puzzled by your set up so i missed the fact that you can keep a bunch of dev branches from different developers in green repo

Comment: Was your problem solved? If so it would be nice if you could accept the answer if it helped or provide your own so other people could benefit from the knowledge